# HTML tables: how to get the following output?

Tags: html, html-table

I've been struggling for over an hour to create a HTML table. I can't understand why it doesn't work or how I should combine the rowspans, colspans. If you could help me, I would be more than grateful to you:

[image]

I tried the following, all failed, some broke my previous templates as well:

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5"></td>
    <td rowspan="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the following:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; } 
td {
   border: 2px solid black;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>    
    <td>C</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you used rowspans of 5 and 3 but the way it works is

you specify a rowspan or colspan and that fills in the grid of cells

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">a</td>
    <td rowspan="5">b</td>
    <td rowspan="3">c</td>
    <td rowspan="3">d</td>
    <td rowspan="3">e</td>
  </tr>
```

Means we have 5 columns and 5 rows (so far)

```
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X|X|X|X| row 1
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X|X|X|X| row 2
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X|X|X|X| row 3
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X| | | | row 4
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X| | | | row 5
+-+-+-+-+-+
```

rows 2 and 3 need no cells (no `<td>`s) because they are already specified by the first row.

row 4 needs 3 `<td>` for the 3 unused cells

```
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">g</td>
    <td rowspan="2">h</td>
    <td rowspan="2">i</td>
  </tr>
```

The grid is now full

```
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X|X|X|X| row 1
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X|X|X|X| row 2
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X|X|X|X| row 3
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X|X|X|X| row 4
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X|X|X|X|X| row 5
+-+-+-+-+-+
```

so row 5 needs no cells (no `<td>`s)

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; } 
td {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">a</td>
    <td rowspan="5">b</td>
    <td rowspan="3">c</td>
    <td rowspan="3">d</td>
    <td rowspan="3">e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">g</td>
    <td rowspan="2">h</td>
    <td rowspan="2">i</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

This should look very closely to what you want to achieve. Important parts are border-collapse, rowspan, width of td, width of border, using class. This is one of many ways to do it.

```css
td {
  border: 4px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.larger-width{
 width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='2' class="larger-width"></td>
    <td rowspan='2' class="larger-width"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="larger-width"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table example</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table td {
            border: 5px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<table border="2" cellpadding="50px">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Output will be

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDgVg.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDgVg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, do modifications as you wish.

```
<table width="346" height="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```